# error after adding a new field in Django Models

Tags: django

My UserProfile was working fine until I changed the model and form. I added a DateField in model and updated my Forms.py and template. Also did a syncdb.

profile/models.py

```
class UserProfiles(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #other fields here
    birthday = models.DateField()
```

profile/forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfiles
        fields = ('some_field', 'birthday', 'otherfields')
```

profile/views.py

```
def editprofile(request):
    return render_to_response('profile_edit.html', {'form':UserProfileForm()}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is the error it is throwing.

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "E:\django-sample\proschools\..\proschools\profile\views.py" in generateprofile
  12.             userprofile = UserProfiles.objects.get(user=request.user)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in get
  132.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  344.         num = len(clone)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
  82.                 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in iterator
  273.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in results_iter
  680.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  735.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  34.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py" in execute
  86.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in execute
  174.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: OperationalError at /profile/
Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'profile_userprofiles.birthday' in 'field list'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table existed before you added the new column `syncdb` will not add new columns to it! `syncdb` [does not alter existing tables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-syncdb). Consider using [Django south](http://south.aeracode.org/) or else add the column manually.

Comment: if i'm creating manually, are there any precautions? Or i just go and add table manually using mysql workbench and thats it?

Comment: @John Ideally you use the south app. However for just one column it may be cumbersome. Executing [sqlall](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sqlall-appname-appname) on your specific `app` tells you exactly what DDL syntax Django itself would have used to create it.

Answer (score 2):

```
http://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/
```

When you run ./manage.py syncdb, Django will look for any new models that have been defined, and add a database table to represent those new models. However, if you make a change to an existing model, ./manage.py syncdb will not make any changes to the database.

This is where Django Evolution fits in. Django Evolution is an extension to Django that allows you to track changes in your models over time, and to update the database to reflect those changes.

Answer (score 1):

Syncdb won't automatically create new fields for you.  You would have to entirely delete the table and run syncdb to apply the schema changes to the DB.

Most django developers use a third party app called [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) to handle these types of migrations. South will let you add fields and migrate the database without having to recreate it or manually alter the database.